Abort piping to grep on first match
Is it possible to pipe from an ongoing process into grep and return to prompt on first match?
docker compose logs -f | grep -m 1 foobar

So after the first match of "foobar" the pipe chain should abort without error and return to prompt.

Try grep -m 1 foobar <(docker compose logs -f)

thx, it solved my problem
